# Store loggedin user information in session and destroy the data after logging out in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.4

I want to store some information of a user in session when he/she logs in to my application. And I want to destroy that session data after that user logs out of my application.

How can I achieve this in Laravel 5.4 with Auth?

Comment: why do you need it customized? laravel already gives this functionality

Comment: You can use Auth::User to get logged in users info

Comment: Yes I know laravel give this functionality. But I want to store those in session variabel instead of Auth::User.

I just want to get the idea of session in laravel 5.4, which we do in core php during login/logout of a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel calls `authenticated` method after a successful login. You can add your session information here so that they get added when a user logs in.

Add this method to `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php`

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    // Store information in session for user
}
```

By default laravel flushes all the session information when a user logs out. By if you want to handle it differently or make changes. Add this to your `LoginController` and make the changes.

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->flush();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

By doing the above you're basically overriding laravel's built in methods and adding additional functionality.

Comment: Thanks @sandeesh for giving the brief idea.